# How to append <asp:Button /> etc.. within the <form> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

Here is my sample code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('body')
            .append('<form id="form1"></form>'); //append a new form element with id mySearch to <body>
        $('#form1')
            .attr("runat", "server")
            .append('<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1"/>');
    });
    </script>
```

This is how my body tag looks like:

```
    <body>

    </body>
```

I get this error:

```
Control 'btn1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Update: I tried to omit the

```
    .append('<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1"/>');
```

When I run the firebug i get this:

```
   <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server"></form>
   </body>
```

It does have a runat="server". Why I can't place my asp:Button inside it? o_O

Comment: Just use a regular input button... that is exactly what an `asp:button` renders as.

Comment: Yes it works, but I want to use asp ctrls like 'asp:Repeater' to bind my data. Is there any other way? Anyway, thanks @MikeSmithDev

Comment: You can't add server controls via Javascript. Why are you even trying to do it? Why can't you just type those controls in the page directly and get rid of your Javascript?

Comment: so it seems like there is no way i can't place any asp ctrls using javascript. Thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updated question is is still a wrong approach. You can't do this:

```
$('#form1').attr("runat", "server")
```

and expect it to work the same as if you typed this:

```
<form runat="server">
```

because the tag above is processed **server side** and actually renders on the **client side** like this:

```
<form method="post" action="default.aspx" id="ctl00">
```

and that looks nothing like what you are doing.

You have two options:

1. Stop trying to add any ASP.NET controls (i.e. starts with `<asp:`) or anything with `runat="server"` in it with Javascript. If you really have to do this with Javascript, then use regular HTML controls.
2. Stop using Javascript and actually correctly use `<asp:` controls or HTML controls with `runat="server"` and then do what you need to do from the code behind.

**And now for the tangent.**

Concerning your error of `Control 'btn1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.` Let's say you correctly use `<form runat="server">` and try again. You may find it (sort of) works!

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="Button 2" runat="server" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%= form1.ClientID %>').append('<asp:Button Text="Button 1" ID="btn1" runat="server"/>');
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

This *will* render, but it is not correct. Besides being confusing, nasty code, it only works because ASP.NET actually renders the HTML for that `<asp:Button` and puts it in the script block, so what is sent to the client is this (and two buttons.. but still not what you typed).

```
<input type="submit" name="btn2" value="Button 2" id="btn2" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').append('<input type="submit" name="btn1" value="Button 1" id="btn1" />');
    });
</script>
```

And now for part you didn't expect. From the code-behind, you can do this on Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1.Text = "This is Awful";
}
```

And instead of having two buttons that say `Button 2` and `Button 1` on the screen, the second button now says `This is Awful`.

...but again, this is totally wrong and will break for most other `<asp:` controls if you try to do it (and I'm not sure why ASP.NET converts the code in the Javascript block at all). So, see the two options above on how you can proceed.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to put an asp ctrl and append it using javascript is because i want to do an animation like slideDown when a user click an asp:Button  asp:Repeater will do slideDown. I think I should take your advice. Thanks @MikeSmithDev!  :)

Comment: @DavidDeChavez what you want to do is still possible, just take a different approach... any problems with new approach, just ask a new question :) Also, I added a little bit more explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this part of code is not run as you expect

```
.append('<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1"/>');
```

the `runat="server"` to work for that control must be added when you design the page, or pro grammatically on server side, compiled by the code behind on server and create an html part.

When you add this with javascript on client, the server did not know anything about and can not run it, nether compile it.

Now in the first part you try to add a new `form` inside the page on client side again

```
$('body')
            .append('<form id="form1"></form>'); 
        $('#form1')
```

This is a problem on webform, because an asp.net must contains only one form element. Inside the one form that all ready rendered by asp.net you need to add additional buttons and not create a second one.

To move on, you need to have define a form tag on the page (not with javascript). If you like to add post back input buttons, you can do but must be place them inside the existing form, with out create new one, and with out the runat=server. And then handle that post back on code behind manually - meaning that you are not going to call any particular function, you just read the post back variables.

Comment: Yes it's true. But I still can't place any asp ctrls when I defined the form tag on my page. Please see my updated question above. Thanks @Aristos

Comment: so it seems like there is no way i can't place any asp ctrls using javascript. Thanks anyway! :D